# Deleting newline by python (Django) by taking string by textarea in html but the answer is wrong. WHY?

Tags: python, html, django, backend

```
print(newlineremove)
print(djtext)
if newlineremove == "on":
    analyzed=""
    print(djtext)
    for char in djtext:
        if char !="\n":
            analyzed=analyzed + char
print(analyzed)
```

suppose newlineremove is on and the input in textarea(html) is:

```
dam
dam
```

djtext=request.GET.get('text','default')

OUTPUT:

```
on
dam 
dam
dam
dam
dam
```

but it  should have been:

```
on
dam 
dam
dam
dam
damdam
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [rstrip](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rstrip.html)

Looking at your code. After using rstrip your code should become:

```
print(newlineremove)
print(djtext)
if newlineremove == "on":
    analyzed=djtext.rstrip()
print(analyzed)
```

**rstrip** simply returns a copy of the string with trailing characters removed.

Answer (score 0):

first:
`analyzed=analyzed + char`
should be:
`analyzed+=analyzed + char`
but I told you to use:
`analyzed=djtext.replace('\n', '')`
so without the for loop.